# In the far future, humans wage war through spaceships that are mentally controlled solely by women. How would this affect the military and society?

Tags: society, space, military, future

A bit more explanation on the premise.

Humans now have extended their territory to the edges of the Milky Way galaxy and have hundreds of colonial planets. However, humans still fight among one another just as we do today.

My idea is that technology has advanced so far that humans now wage war solely through mentally controlled space warships. However, scientists discovered that only women for some reason could be able to operate such a technology. So, for example one woman officer would control a squadron of let's say 100 ships. Then, a fleet admiral would command and give tactical instructions to let's say 10 officers. Officers would occasionally give advice but the final decision would always be up to the admiral.

Admirals could either be a man or woman and would be selected solely based on their tactical brilliance. But, the percentage of male admirals would be around 85% in my world.

How would this affect the structure of society and the military as well?

Comment: Hi, user107257, welcome to Worldbuilding! So, in this world only women can be pilots, but the fleet needs only a few of them?

Comment: @Alexander Not pilots per say. They can mentally control up to 100 warships. So even a small number of female officers like 10 would be to control 1000 warships already.

Comment: Ok, but do warships need any crew, or they are automated drones?

Comment: They are fully automated. There is nobody on board.

Comment: Welcome! Do take a moment to check out the [help] and [tour] so you can get a better idea how this forum works.  As written, your question seems a bit broad. You're asking about effects on both military and society at large. We like single focused questions, so I'd ask you to choose which one you wish to focus on and edit accordingly.  You're certainly welcome to explore the other question separately if you think there might be good reason to.

Comment: So, Kancolle In Space, then? ;)

Comment: *Admirals could either be a man or woman and would be selected solely based on their tactical brilliance. But, the percentage of male admirals would be around 85% in my world.*  Very peculiar, given that women are the ones doing the fighting and controlling units.  They would inevitably learn more tactical and strategic skills that men *not* doing that job.

Comment: @StephenG that's an interesting counterpoint. In my mind, I was imagining the admirals in training would undergo intense tactical training and studying thus the reason for their tactical brilliance when compared to the regular female officers. Males tend to be better at strategy in general so that's why more males would excel in the admiral academy.

Comment: *Males tend to be better at strategy in general*  I'm aware of no scientific basis for this statement.  If experience teaches anything it's that a general detached from the reality of front-line combat (and lacking personal experience of it) will expect too much from front line units.  In addition their commands often carry no credibility with front line soldiers.  They say that battle plans are generally not going to survive past the first phase of an engagement.  Frontline experience is a *must*.

Comment: I would recommend you flesh out the military structure yourself, then ask us if there would be any redundancies or improvements that could be made on it. It looks like you have a great idea ( instantly reminds me of Kancolle ) and that you are seeking further opinions and ideas to help expand upon it.

Comment: "what are the effects of X on society?" is always too broad. And you are also adding the military

Comment: i can at least see the woman here probably more focus on the tactical and battle formation at least, also is there exist human soldier or it also control like psychic drone soldier? personally i think the men have higher chance to be the admiral since women can control the ship so its such a waste to turn her into admiral which more focus in commanding the officer and strategy. which not neccessary for her to personally also control the ship too it can leave to some women assistant, and is there a range limit of commanding/control the ship?

Comment: @StephenG I was roughly basing my idea around Ender's Game's concept where one commander controls the entire fleet. The MC was also detached from combat as you have said but somehow it worked in the novel.

Comment: @LiJun more like psychic drones/ships with no men manning them.

Comment: no i mean is there a land base kind of soldier or it also use the drone type too not the fleet personnel, since it probably still need land base or planetary soldier to maintain or occupation of the territory.

Comment: @LiJun ah i get you. For land based combat, actual humans will still be doing the fighting. The psychic/remote warfare only applies to space battles.

Answer (score 2):

There's a whole lot of answers based on what you may or may not believe about the differences between the sexes.  However, there's one that is glaringly obvious: there's a *mighty* gap which cannot be filled by both sexes!

If we consider [our current command structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Military_organization), 100 individuals are typically controlled by a lieutenant, captain, or major.  Ten times that, 1000 individuals or more, is typically controlled by a colonel or general.

Which means, should we treat a single ship as we treat an individual soldier today, your generals have never seen *any* rank besides general.

If we devalue a warship to be 0.5 soldiers, we start to enter a regime where women may be equivalent to warrant offices, which has some interesting historical arguments that may be brought forth.  If we devalue it to 0.25 solders, we start to get into the realm where women mirror our current enlisted soldiers, and men mirror our current officers.

On the other hand, if we rank warships as larger than a soldier, women start to push into the general range.  If we consider a warship comparable to a modern Arleigh Burke destroyer, its a command of about 250 men.  100 of these would be 25,000 men, which is on par with a three star general.

These numbers suggest that, somehow, your men managed to command the respect of a general status (or even a four or five star general status), without ever having seen a lower rank.

Given that, I think its fair to say that your military structure will bear virtually no resemblance to modern military hierarchy.  You'll have to invent the entire thing from scratch.  You'll have to work out all of the strategy and tactics and everything inbetween, then iterate it for a few hundred (or thousand) years to find out what happens.

Comment: *"These numbers suggest that, somehow, your men managed to command the respect of a general status (or even a four or five star general status), without ever having seen a lower rank."* ["When I was a lad I served a term; As office boy to an attorney's firm; I cleaned the windows and I swept the floor; And I polished up the handle of the big front door; *He polished up the handle of the big front door*; I polished up that handle so carefully; That now I am the Ruler of the Queen's Navy"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HMS_Pinafore) - see also, William Henry Smith (junior) of Newsagent fame...

Comment: @Chronocidal I keep failing to bookmark the article, but there's a fascinating story from Her Majesty's Navy of a warrant officer assuming command of a fleet.  He was aboard the flagship of a fleet when a shell struck and killed the admiral of the fleet, the captain of the ship, and all of the other officers on board.  The lad worked through the chain of command rules, determined he was now ranking officer on the flag ship, and began issuing orders to the fleet.  Needless to say, he fared poorly and the fleet was defeated soundly.  Much later, the captains of the fleet...

Comment: ... court martialed the lad when they got back to England.  After all, had he given command to *any* of the other captains, they would have had a fighting chance.  However, it was found that the lad actually did indeed follow the letter of the law regarding the chain of command, and was cleared of all wrongdoing.